# Apache Guacamole-Creating New connection to Windows PC

Tags: apache

I have successfully installed Apache Guacamole on my DigitalOcean VPS.

Now I need to create a new connection to my windows 10 pc.

I cannot get that to work.

I am very confused what settings I need to fill in to connect to the pc.

Here are screenshots of the settings I can fill in. I am going to use RDP and am unsure how to find the domain, host, etc of my pc. Maybe there is other settings I need to fill in too?

Please help as I have been trying for weeks. Thank You.

[New Connection Settings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5NXa.png)

[New Connection Settings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgxB2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that both tomcat and guacd services are running. Usually, both are installed on the same machine.

On the settings page, select RDP as the protocol (in the images you have posted, VNC is selected). Next, in the "Parameters" section, enter hostname ip and RDP port (3389 is the default). If guacd is on the same host as tomcat, there is no need to enter anything in the "Guacamole proxy parameter" section.

The settings page is a bit different when RDP is selected, but you should also populate windows username, password and domain of the remote PC where you want to connect. The parameters are the same as the one you are normally using to logon to this PC.

Also, make sure that the remote windows 10 PC is accessible from the DigitalOcean VPS. You may test this by logging to the VPS machine and issue the following in the terminal

```
telnet <remote windows pc ip> 3389
```

If you can connect with telnet, this means that remote PC RDP server is accessible; otherwise, you have to check for network related issues (firewall, different lans...).

If everything above is ok, then please post the tomcat log (catalina.out) and guacd log (usually in /var/log/syslog).

Comment: Thank You, that is what I need it worked!  Now I got to figure out how to make a new user account everytime someone logs into the pc.